# Firebase storage download file to URI on Android

Tags: android, uri, firebase-storage, ioexception

I use Firebase storage to store images after they have been selected in the gallery or from the camera. I have a function `createUriForFile()` which I use to get an `URI` to store the image locally. When an image is selected it is stored in the correct place and, using glide and the same `createUriForFile()` as before, it is shown and also correctly uploaded to Firebase. But when I use an other emulator than the one the images were taken on and I try to download the image, it throws an `Java.io.IOException: no such file or directory`. I don't understand why because everything works with that specific `URI` except downloading it to save it on the device.

I know the settings and code for Firebase are correct, because when I use a `File` as target instead of an `URI` the image is downloaded and displayed(API <= 28). But since Android 29 we can't use direct file access anymore(I want to store the image in a shared folder to display it in the gallery). I understand you can use `inputStream` and `outputStream` but that seems so much work as the `getFile()` accepts an `URI` as argument. So I figure it must be something I'm doing wrong. It doesn't work on API 29 nor on <= 28. The directories are created when the app tries to download the file and it works while saving and uploading, so the `URI` seems to be okay.

I have added the `fileprovider` to the manifest file and added the paths to the xml file.

createUriForFile:

```
EXTERNAL_PICTURE_RELATIVE_PATH = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.separator + baseActivity.getString(R.string.app_name);
EXTERNAL_PICTURE_STORAGE_DIR = baseActivity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + EXTERNAL_PICTURE_RELATIVE_PATH;

public Uri createUriForFile(String fileName, String parentId)
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    {
        //check if there is already an entry in ContentResolver
        Uri uriFromContentResolver = getUriFromContentResolver(fileName);
        if(uriFromContentResolver != null)
        {
            return uriFromContentResolver;
        }else
        {
            ContentResolver resolver = baseActivity.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, EXTERNAL_PICTURE_RELATIVE_PATH);
            return resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
        }
    }else
    {
        checkAndCreatePictureDir(parentId);
        File pictureFile = new File(EXTERNAL_PICTURE_STORAGE_DIR + File.separator + parentId + File.separator + fileName);

        return FileProvider.getUriForFile(baseActivity.getBaseContext(), baseActivity.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", pictureFile);
    }
}
```

Stacktrace for error:

```
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
 Code: -13000 HttpResult: 200
No such file or directory
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1008)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.processResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.0:1072)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Any help or hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: can you please share the full stack trace, not just the first line of it?

Comment: Added the stack trace.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While searching for a solution, I doubled checked the Firebase documentation. I found this:

```
getFile(Uri destinationUri)
Asynchronously downloads the object at this StorageReference to a specified system filepath.
```

Although I did not see it the first couple of times, and it says it can accept an `URI`, it apparently still needs a real path to a file on the system. So I've decided to go with using `inputStream` and `outputStream` to write the data via the `ContentResolver`

Comment: But what you give is a vague answer, you did not show how to solve it neither the step or code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the permission in the Android Manifest and declare a meta data tag

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
    </provider>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I have this set.